# Filter/extract a whole line from my stdout in ansible

Tags: ansible

I am running my shell script from ansible playbook using command module. My playbook prints some messages & error messages like(ansible console output):

```
rc: 1
start: '2020-04-30 10:42:44.165313'
stderr: ''
stderr_lines: <omitted>
stdout: |-
User verified
Ping test okay
ERROR!!! Unable to connect to machine..Aborted...:Error741
```

I captured the command output in register `variable(output_1)`. Now I want to extract 'ERROR' message line from above output. I used `regex_search(output_1.stdout | regex_search('Error741'))` but that is giving me exact word(say Error741) not whole line.

My expected output:-

```
"ERROR!!! Unable to connect to machine.. exiting....:Error741"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the regex like this.

```
{{ output_1.stdout | regex_search('.*Error741') }}
```

With the `stdout` text in your example, this regex will return below line.

```
ERROR!!! Unable to connect to machine..Aborted...:Error741
```

Also [check more details on regex filter here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters).